# Ethernet wire disconnects wifi

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I'm using a fingerprint reader on ethernet, and when i plugg in, the wifi get disconnected, not desactivated, just disconnected. I can't figure what's wrong so maybe you will.

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn't sound like the sort of question for stackoverflow. Also, we don't have enough information to go on, but having said that: it's fairly common for devices to just switch to the most robust network available, and wired trumps unwired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the BIOS. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score -1):

What is the benefit of having both connections going at the same time. You can only utilize one and i would want to utilize the strong one of the two.   A developer would say that is by design. Disconnect or connected and not utilize == the same thing.

Comment: As I told you, I'm using a fingerprint reader via direct ethernet, but still, I need wifi to have internet.